# ngpus_excl_p in LSF

Tags: gpu, nvidia, lsf

ngpus_excl_p: Number of GPUs in exclusive process mode, since only one context is allowed per GPU, does this mean that GPU resources are underutilized in a multi-user scenario where the user does not use entire GPU memory?

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean that GPU resources are underutilized in a multi-user scenario where the user does not use entire GPU memory?

You're right about that.  However, it's common for users to want exclusive access to a GPU.

If the GPUs are in shared mode, then LSF will dispatch multiple jobs to a single GPU, gpu mem is used to limit the jobs on shared mode GPUs.

Jobs that want exclusive access to a GPU, but multiple processes that all interact with the GPU; these kinds of jobs can be supported by putting the GPU in shared mode and use `j_exclusive=yes` in the gpu request.

e.g.,

```
bsub -gpu num=1:j_exclusive=yes my_job_command ...
```

Comment: thanks, so the mention of multiple processes, is it by the same user?

Comment: Yes. multiple processes in the same job.  So also the same user.